# Regex or split in python for shell awk equivalent

Tags: python, regex, bash, awk, split

I've a agent version file that I need to parse to get the application version details.
The (example) contents of version file `/opt/app_folder/agent_version.txt` is as below:

```
Version: 10.2.4.110
Pkg name: XXXX-10.2.4-Agent-Linux-x86_64
Revision: 110
Patch version: 23
```

I need the output as 1st 3 numbers from `Version` and the number from `Release version`.
For e.g.:

```
Current Version: 10.2.4.23
```

So, I've used the below to achieve this in shell using `awk`

```
FILE=/opt/app_folder/agent_version.txt

my_ver=`awk -F[:.] '/Version/ {gsub(" ",""); print $2"."$3"."$4}' ${FILE}`
            OR
my_ver=`awk -F[-] '/Pkg/ {print $2}' ${FILE}`

my_patch=`awk -F[:.] '/version/ {gsub(" ",""); print $NF}' ${FILE}`
my_cur_ver="$my_ver.$my_patch"

echo $my_cur_ver
10.2.4.23
```

How do I achieve this result in Python? Use regex or split or a combination of both?

I'm using `Python 3.3` on `RHEL 6.2 x86_64`

Comment: you should include your Python efforts to solve using `regex/split` as well to question... because that is your problem statement.. bash/awk solution is only extra information..

Comment: @talz it's only been an hour since he asked the question - give the guy a few hours at least to see what answers he gets before having to select one!

Comment: @Sundeep , I didn't try much..almost to the point of 'Not at all', as I'm a 'Very' Noobie in python and didn't knew how to proceed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `txt` holds the contents of the file, this would get you the version:

```
import re
version = re.findall("Version:\s+((?:\d+\.){3})", txt)[0] + re.findall("Patch version:\s+(\d+)", txt)[0]
```

Or if you prefer to only have one regular expression:

```
version = ''.join(re.findall("Version:\s+((?:\d+\.){3}).*Patch version:\s+(\d+)", txt, re.DOTALL)[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/Version/{split($NF,a,".");next} /Patch version/{print a[1],a[2],a[3],$NF}' OFS="."  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
10.2.4.23
```

Comment: @Sundeep, awk is tagged in question, let me know on same else I will delete my solution then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 , Will it work on Python directly? Use subprocess or something...can you elaborate a bit more on your command.

Comment: @Marcos, yes we could call it in Python. Let me add explanation to code now too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks...I've added +1 as ur code helps makes my awk command 1-liner in case I use shell.

Answer (score 2):

Or parse it into a dict and retrieve the needed parts:

```
txt = """Version: 10.2.4.110
Pkg name: XXXX-10.2.4-Agent-Linux-x86_64
Revision: 110
Patch version: 23"""  

# with open("yourfile.txt") as f: 
#     txt = f.read()

dic = {}
for l in txt.splitlines():   # split the blob into lines
    k,v = l.split(":",2)     # split at first : produce 2 items max
    dic.setdefault( k.strip(),v.strip().split("."))  # add to dict & split at . into list

v =  '.'.join(dic["Version"][:-1]+dic["Patch version"] ) # join correct things together 

print(v)
```

Output:

```
10.2.4.23
```

It is overall a bit wastefull, but works w/o regex.

Just for completeness: `dic` looks like this:

```
{'Revision': ['110'], 
 'Patch version': ['23'], 
 'Version': ['10', '2', '4', '110'], 
 'Pkg name': ['XXXX-10', '2', '4-Agent-Linux-x86_64']}
```

Comment: added +1 for using dict, I prefer using regex

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `(?:Version:\s?((?:\d+\.){3})(?:[^\r\n]+\r?\n){3}Patch version:\s?(\d+))`

**Substitution**: `$1$2`

```
Match 1
....
Group 1.    9-16    `10.2.4.`
Group 2.    90-92   `23`
```

**Output**:

```
10.2.4.23
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mw2WYq/4)

```
import re

text = 'Version: 10.2.4.110\r\nPkg name: XXXX-10.2.4-Agent-Linux-x86_64\r\nRevision: 110\r\nPatch version: 23'

replaced = re.sub(r'(?:Version:\s?((?:\d+\.){3})(?:[^\r\n]+\r?\n){3}Patch version:\s?(\d+))', '\g<1>\g<2>', text)
print(replaced) //10.2.4.23
```

Comment: Do we really need \r\n in regex instead of \n, as I&amp;#39;ll be running the code only on Linux hosts...Never on Windows...The regex doesn't seem to work on my Linux hosts